# Pebble app not receiving String from phone

Tags: java, android, c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm creating a very simple pebble app.

**Goal:**
When I click on my Android app, for the Pebble app to display the message I'm sending from my Android app.

**Issue:**
Text does not change/display on the pebble.

**Code**

Pebble .c code:

```
#include "pebble_os.h"
#include "pebble_app.h"
#include "pebble_fonts.h"


#define MY_UUID { 0x98, 0x15, 0xA8, 0xDA, 0x6C, 0xAC, 0x40, 0xB0, 0xAD, 0x87, 0xFC, 0xDF, 0x9E, 0x86, 0x3E, 0x91 }
PBL_APP_INFO(MY_UUID,
             "Phone App", "Me",
             1, 0, /* App version */
             DEFAULT_MENU_ICON,
             APP_INFO_STANDARD_APP);

Window window;
TextLayer hello_layer;
AppMessageCallbacksNode messageCallBacks;

void myMessageHandler(DictionaryIterator* received, void* context) {
    vibes_short_pulse();
    Tuple* tuple = dict_find(received, 0);
    text_layer_set_text(&hello_layer, tuple->value->cstring);
}

void handle_init(AppContextRef ctx) {
    messageCallBacks = (AppMessageCallbacksNode) {
        .callbacks = {
            .in_received = myMessageHandler
        },
        .context = NULL
    };
  window_init(&window, "Window Name");
  window_stack_push(&window, true /* Animated */);

  text_layer_init(&hello_layer, GRect(0, 65, 144, 30));
  text_layer_set_text(&hello_layer, "Hello World!");
  layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(&window), (Layer*)&hello_layer);
}


void pbl_main(void *params) {
  PebbleAppHandlers handlers = {
    .init_handler = &handle_init,
      .messaging_info = {
          .buffer_sizes = {
              .inbound = 64,
              .outbound = 64
          }
      }
  };
  app_event_loop(params, &handlers);
}
```

Android Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button send;
    private Context context;
    UUID AppId = UUID
            .fromString("9815A8DA-6CAC-40B0-AD87-FCDF9E863E91");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        context = this;

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        PebbleDictionary data = new PebbleDictionary();
                        data.addString(0, "TEST");
                        PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble(getApplicationContext(), AppId, data);

                    }

                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a call to `app_message_register_callbacks` in your `handle_init` method.

Adding this should do the trick:

```
app_message_register_callbacks(&messageCallBacks);
```

You are still using SDK 1.x which is now deprecated. I strongly recommend that you upgrade to SDK 2.0. The development and debugging tools are much nicer. You will also have way more APIs to play with.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I got: expected 'struct AppMessageCallbacksNode *' but argument is of type 'AppMessageCallbacksNode, so I tried to change it to app_message_register_callbacks(&messageCallBacks); which compiled but does not get the String from the phone. Thanks once again.

Comment: Oh man, I'm incredibly stupid. I never started the thread on my phone. Thanks so much, can't believe I made such a dumb mistake.

Comment: Glad to know it is working now. I have updated my answer to fix the type problem, thanks for pointing that out.